# switch case, user input, determine what character it is

Tags: c++

I have a bunch of if statements. But I want to have that bunch of if statements in a switch. I try it like this:

```
// project_stringManipulation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    char input;
    cin >> input;

    switch (input)
    {
    case isalpha(input) :       
        cout << "That's an alphabetic character.\n";
    default:
        break;
    }


    cout << "Enter any character: ";
    cin.get(input);
    cout << "The character you entered is: " << input << endl;
    cin.get();
    if (isalpha(input))
        cout << "That's an alphabetic character.\n";
    cin.get();
    if (isdigit(input))
        cout << "That's a numeric digit.\n";
    cin.get();
    if (islower(input))
        cout << "The letter you entered is lowercase.\n";
    cin.get();
    if (isupper(input))
        cout << "The letter you entered is uppercase.\n";
    cin.get();
    if (isspace(input))
        cout << "That's a whitespace character.\n";

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}
```

But then I will get on this line:

```
case isalpha(input) :
```

The following error:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)      expression must have a constant value   project_stringManipulation  d:\Mijn Documents\VisualStudio2015\C++_Programs\Program_Nice\project_stringManipulation\project_stringManipulation.cpp  19
```

How to do it on the correct way?

Thank you

Comment: please read about how a `switch` statement works. The value of `input` is unlikely to be equal to `isalpha(input)`

Comment: "I want to" Why? What's wrong with a bunch of `if` statements? Especially when they encode conditions that are **not** mutually exclusive, such as `isalpha` and `islower`?

Answer (score 0):

When you write:

```
switch (input) {
    case {something}:
    break;
    ...
}
```

Then `something` is evaluated against `input` as in: `(input == something)`. If `input` is indeed equal to `something` then the case expression is `true` and your code will execute.

The issue is that you are evaluating `input` to the result of `isalpha()` which is a boolean.

Say `input = "a"`. Then, `isAlpha(input)` will return `true`.

Now your case says execute if `"a" == true` which is false, so your code doesn't execute.

If you wanted to structure this as a switch you could write something like:

```
switch (true) {
    case isalpha(input):
    //Do stuff
    break;
    ...
}
```

### Also,

As mentioned by Dark Falcon in the comments, case statements must be constant values in C++.

Comment: Except in C++, a `case`'s value must be a constant, making any attempt to call `isalpha` within the case expression invalid.

Comment: Thanks, will add that to the answer.

Comment: imho `switch(true)...` is a great way to obfuscate code. There can be only to cases, so why use `switch` when `if-else` clearly expresses the intent?

Comment: @Alexander. So the end conclusion is: you cant do a switch statement in this situation. Because the case value has to be a constant. Because I tried your example. But that doesn't work.

Comment: @HoicodeEngineerKing that's right, just stick to if-else.